# Android: Change table row color when it clicks and remove the color when click anothe row of the table

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

In my android app there is a table layout which is loading at run time. I've implemented a code to change background color of this table when the row is clicked.

```
private OnClickListener trOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TableRow tablerow = (TableRow)v;

        tablerow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.table_row_selector));


    }
};
```

Now I want to remove this color when the user clicks another row of the table and newly clicked row should change it's color.

This is my drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_whiteaction" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/table_shape" android:state_enabled="true"/>
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanx in advcance

Comment: please show the code for your drawable if its a xml resource file.

Comment: @Neil I've edited my question. Plz help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your drawable to look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_selected" android:state_enabled="true"
          android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_selected" android:state_enabled="true"
          android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_selected" android:state_enabled="true"
          android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_selected" android:state_active="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_selectable" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_selectable" android:state_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_selectable" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_selectable" android:state_active="false"/>
</selector>
```

Then you set your row to `tablerow.setSelected(true)`. When another row is selected, set the previous selected row to `tablerow.setSelected(false)` and the newly selected row to `true`

I use this in one of my `ListViews` and it works.

Hope this helps

Comment: How can I identify table rows. I've used tr.setTag(). Can I use it to identify previous selected row and newly selected row?

Comment: You'll have to save the selected view in some kind of global variable or something like that. You're getting the view in onClick(View v) so maybe use that view. Something like v.setSelected(true) and currentSelected.setSelected(false) and then currentSelected = v;

Comment: Yes it is a global variable that you have to set. Just do a check if it's null the first time you set it to false

Comment: I've initialized it as null. is it ok? private View currentSelected = null;

Comment: Yeah as long as you do the null check in onClick

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing from xml use selectors, and apply as background or source..

Answer (score 0):

Create a field: View restoredView

```
row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (restoredView != null) {
            restoredView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
        }
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DDDDDD"));
        restoredView = view;
    }
});
```